# ReactJS this.state null

Tags: javascript, state, reactjs

Let me preface this by saying I am a novice to ReactJS. I am trying to learn by making a simple site that populates data using React. I have a JSON file that contains link data that will be looped through with map.

I have tried setting it as the components state then passing it to the navbar links via a prop but I am getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null"

I tried to look around for solutions but could not find anything.

Note: When I try to hard code an object and map through it that way it returns map is undefined. However I am not sure that is directly related to the setState error.

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var conf = {
    companyName: "Slant Hosting"
  };

var NavbarLinks = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    var navLinks = this.props.data.map(function(link){
      return(
        <li><a href={link.target}>{link.text}</a></li>
      );
    });
    return(
      <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
        {navLinks}
      </ul>
    )
  }
});

var NavbarBrand = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return(
      <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">{conf.companyName}</a>
    );
  }
});

var Navbar = React.createClass({
  getInitalState: function(){
    return{
      data : []
    };
  },
  loadNavbarJSON: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "app/js/configs/navbar.json",
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({
          data: data
        });
        console.log(data);
        console.log(this.state.data);
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
  componentDidMount: function(){
    this.loadNavbarJSON();
  },
  render: function(){
    return(
      <nav className="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <div className="navbar-header">
            <NavbarBrand />
          </div>
          <NavbarLinks data={this.state.data} />
        </div>
      </nav>
    );
  }
});

var Header = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return(
      <Navbar />
    );
  }
});

React.renderComponent(
  <Header />,
  document.getElementById('render')
);
```

Comment: you misspelled `getInitialState` (you're missing the 'i' right after the t in initial)

Comment: Looks like @trekforever found your problem. As as aside, your `console.log(this.state.data)` probably won't print the correct results, as React will queue the `setState` call. If you want to print your state after a call to `setState` you have to supply a callback: 
`this.setState({something: 'blah'}, function() { console.log(this.state.something);});`

Comment: @edoloughlin Thanks for the additional info!

Comment: I just had this problem, too. "Heh, a misspelling, how careless," I thought. Then I went and checked my code. I had also misspelled it. The exact same way. 

Answer (score 82):

Using ES6, the initial state must be created in your constructor for the React component class, like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state ={
    // Set your state here
    }
}
```

See [this documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html).

Comment: This one helps me.

  constructor(props: any)
    {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            model: new RegistrationModel()
        }

and NOT 

this.setState

}

Thanks

Comment: This worked for me. I was using this.setState(obj) in my constructor. Any reason why your approach worked over mine?

Answer (score 20):

This question has already been answered, but I came here by having a problem that can easily happen to anyone.

I was getting a `console.log(this.state)` to log `null` in one of my methods, just because I didn't write:

> this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this);

in my constructor.

So, if you're getting a `null` for this.state in one of your methods, check if you have bounded it to your component.

Cheers!

**Edit** (because of @tutiplain's question)

Why was I getting `null` for `this.state`?

Because I wrote `console.log(this.state)` in the method which wasn't bounded to my class (my handleSelect method). That caused `this` to point to some object higher in the object hierarchy (most probably the `window` object) which doesn't have a property named `state`. So, by binding my `handleSelect` method to `this`, I assured that whenever I write `this` in that method, it will point to the object in which the method is in.

I encourage you to read a really good explanation for this [here](http://reactkungfu.com/2015/07/why-and-how-to-bind-methods-in-your-react-component-classes/).

Comment: This one actually helped me. Lots of outdated tutorials out there. But I don't understand why it works. If I am in the same class, isn't the state object shared between all methods of that class? Why do I have to manually bind "this" to the method?

Comment: I edited my comment with a brief explanation. Make sure to check out the link I left at the end. :)

Answer (score 11):

`this.state.data` is null in your example because `setState()` is async. Instead you can pass a callback to setState like so:

```
loadNavbarJSON: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "app/js/configs/navbar.json",
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);

        this.setState({data: data}, function(){
          console.log(this.state.data);
        }.bind(this));

      }.bind(this),
    });
  }
```

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate

Answer (score 10):

More actual answer, for using ES7+ Classes:

```
export class Counter extends React.Component {
  state = { data : [] };
  ...
}
```

ES6 Classes (alredy was answered)

```
export class Component extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { data : [] };
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. In my case it was `webpack-dev-server` not re-compiling my stuff on the run properly.
I just restarted the dev server to get it working again.